Django works perfectly on a local machine, but doesn't work in production
Django works perfectly on a local machine, but has errors with Postgres in production (I am using the same postgres DB in prod and locally).
Django server hosted on Railway gives me this:
Settings (WORKS PERFECTLY ON A LOCAL MACHINE WITH THIS IN-PROD DATABASE AND SAVES DATA):
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
    'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
  }
}
DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')

.env:
DATABASE_PRIVATE_URL={{DATABASE_PRIVATE_URL}}
DATABASE_URL={{DATABASE_URL}}
DB_HOST=viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net
DB_NAME=railway
DB_PASSWORD={{DB_PASSWORD}}
DB_PORT=19232
DB_USER=postgres
SECRET_KEY={{SECRET_KEY}}

Proof for local server working:
Postgres server logs (local machine):



How exactly are you loading the .env file into the production environment?  Django does not support those files by default.

DATABASE_URL={{DATABASE_URL}} Also that syntax with the curly braces looks odd.  Does that really work?

Obviously the production instance does not have Postgres running/listening on the local Unix socket. What does running locally vs running in production mean in practical terms?

@JohnGordon I just didn't show the actual url, whatever's in {{}} is a variable and I am not showing the actual values: postgresql://postgres:{{DB_PASSWORD}}@{{DB_HOST}}:19232/railway

@AdrianKlaver So by running Django locally I meant that I started a Django server with the command: python3 manage.py runserver; And by running Django in production I mean deploying it on the railway server, but the postgres database configuration is the same

If the configuration where the same you would not be having a problem. Is this happening on the same 'machine'(virtual or real)? Though from this Railway I would say not on the same machine.

Postgresql (pgsql) client expecting sockets in different location from postgrsql-server - Stack Overflow

@furas Thanks but now I have a bigger problem... Explained it here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339331/railway-problems-with-connecting-to-postgres-in-production

@AdrianKlaver Here, more details are provided. Don't know what to do at this point: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339331/railway-problems-with-connecting-to-postgres-in-production
